# Active nav bar menu item and add scroll status when page scroll

Tags: css, reactjs

When page load I want to make first nav item  menu active, then user user click on another nav item then active status should move to select nav item and change active  nav item status on scroll.  I have used smooth-scroll for scrolling. How can we do it?

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState('Home');


  const handleMenuClick = () => {
    setClick(!click);
  };

  const handleLinkClick = (link) => {
    setActiveLink(link);
    setClick(false);
  };
 <div className="navbar-links-container">
          <ul className= "nav-items">
            <li >
              <a href="#Home"  className="page-scroll dropdown">
                Home
              </a>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#First">drop-1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#Second">drop-2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#Third">drop-3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
           
            <li>
              <a href="#About" className={activeLink === 'About' ? 'active' : ''}
                onClick={() => handleLinkClick('Blogs')}>>
                About Us
              </a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
              <a href="#Blog" className={activeLink === 'Blogs' ? 'active' : ''}
                onClick={() => handleLinkClick('Blogs')}>
                Blogs
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Contact" className={activeLink === 'Contact' ? 'active' : ''}
                onClick={() => handleLinkClick('Contact')}>>
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**/for css/**

```
 .navbar-links-container .nav-items a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #a112b3;
}

.nav-items li.active > a {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #a112b3;
}`
```

first nav item active on load and nav items status changes on scroll